# Is there a way to make all pages in a menu have a slug in the URL?

Tags: url

I have a page for "Froggy Park" on my Joomla site, and right now it is at `www.site.com/forkids/froggypark` but I want the park to be at `www.site.com/parks/forkids/froggypark`

The page is already in a menu called "Parks" which has a menu header called "For Kids" then there is a menu item "Froggy Park" under that header.  How can I make "/parks/" appear in the url?

Comment: Assuming that you researched and made some attempts to self-resolve this issue before asking your question, please [edit] your question to include 1. links to references that you found which did not resolve the issue and 2. your personal attempts to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, I have been trying to solve this for years and a google search turns up this question. Do you know the solution?